# Search logs within date/time range

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I, Newbie, have searched this forum high and low, and have tried several awks, seds, & greps.

I am trying to search log files to output all logs within a date & time.

Unfortunately, the logs that I am searching all have **different date formats**.

I **did** get this one to work:

```
awk '$0 >= "2018-08-23.11:00:00" && $0 <= "2018-08-23.14:00:00"' catalina.out
```

for that specific date format.

I **can't** get these date formats to work, maybe an issue with the spacing?

2018-08-23 11:00:00, or Aug 23, 2018 11:00:00

**Some** examples of what I have tried:

```
sed -n '/2018-08-23 16:00/,/2018-08-23 18:00/p' testfile.txt
sed -n '/Feb 23 13:55/,/Feb 23 14:00/p' testfile.txt
awk '$0 >= "2018-08-23 17:00:00" && $0 <= "2018-08-23 19:00:00"' testfile.txt
```

I have also tried setting variables:
 FROM="Aug 23, 2018 17:00:00" , TO="Aug 23, 2018 19:00:00"

```
awk '$0 >= "$FROM" && $0 <= "$TO"' testfile.txt
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**UPDATE**: I got THIS to work for the 2018-08-23 11:00:00 format

```
grep -n '2018-08-23 11:[0-9][0-9]' testfile.txt | head -1
grep -n '2018-08-23 12:[0-9][0-9]' testfile.txt | tail -1
awk 'NR>=2 && NR<=4' testfile.txt > rangeoftext
```

But I could not get it to work with the Aug 23, 2018 11:00:00 -- again, I think this may be a space issue?  Not sure how to resolve....

Comment: `grep` is for doing `g/re/p` and `sed` is for doing `s/old/new/`. Neither of those is what you're trying to do so you shouldn't have even considered `grep` or `sed`. For all other text manipulation, e.g. the problem you describe, you should be using `awk`. If you post a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output then we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should look at Splunk.  Its one of the best tool to handle logs. It takes most date format an you can make nice graps.

Answer (score 2):

This is a difficult problem. `grep` and `sed` have no concept of a date, and even GNU `awk` has only limited support for dates and times.

The problem becomes somewhat more tractable if you use a sane date format, i.e. a date format that can be used in string comparisons, such as `2018-08-15 17:00:00`. This should work regardless of whether the string contains whitespace or not. However, beware of tools that automatically split on whitespace, such as the shell and `awk`.

Now, to your examples:

```
sed -n '/2018-08-23 16:00/,/2018-08-23 18:00/p' testfile.txt
sed -n '/Feb 23 13:55/,/Feb 23 14:00/p' testfile.txt
awk '$0 >= "2018-08-23 17:00:00" && $0 <= "2018-08-23 19:00:00"' testfile.txt
```

The first two should work, but only if the file really contains both timestamps, since you are only checking for the presence of certain arbitrary strings. The third should also work, provided that the records all start with a timestamp.

Comment: Thank you, this is one of the simplest and working answers i've found

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're looking for (making some assumptions about what your input file might look like):

```
$ cat file
Aug 22, 2018 11:00:00 bad
2018-08-23 11:00:00 good
Aug 23, 2018 11:00:00 good
2018-08-24 11:00:00 bad

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    min = raw2dt(min)
    max = raw2dt(max)
}
{ cur = raw2dt($0) }
(cur >= min) && (cur <= max)

function raw2dt(raw,    tmp, mthNr, dt, fmt) {
    fmt = "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d"
    if ( match(raw,/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}( [0-9:]+)?/) ) {
        split(substr(raw,RSTART,RLENGTH),tmp,/[^[:alnum:]]+/)
        dt = sprintf(fmt, tmp[1], tmp[2], tmp[3], tmp[4], tmp[5], tmp[6])
    }
    else if ( match(raw,/[[:alpha:]]{3} [0-9]{2}, [0-9]{4}( [0-9:]+)?/) ) {
        split(substr(raw,RSTART,RLENGTH),tmp,/[^[:alnum:]]+/)
        mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",tmp[1])+2)/3
        dt = sprintf(fmt, tmp[3], mthNr, tmp[2], tmp[4], tmp[5], tmp[6])
    }
    return dt
}

$ awk -v min='Aug 23, 2018 11:00' -v max='2018-08-23 11:00' -f tst.awk file
2018-08-23 11:00:00 good
Aug 23, 2018 11:00:00 good
```

The above will work using any POSIX awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to obtain a set of log-entries which appear between two dates, one should never use `sed` to check for this. Yes it is true that sed has a cool and very useful feature to check address ranges (so does awk btw.) but

```
sed -n `/date1/,/date2/p` file
```

will not always work. This means it will only work if `date1` and `date2` are actually in the file. If one of them is missing, this will fail.

> An editing command with two addresses shall select the inclusive range from the first pattern space that matches the first address through the next pattern space that matches the second.
>
> ```
> [address[,address]]
> ```

On top of that, when comparing dates, one should never use string comparisons unless you use a sane format. Some sane formats are `YYYY-MM-DD`, `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`, ... Some bad formats are "Aug 1 2018" as it comes before "Jan 1 2018" and "99-01-31" comes after "01-01-31", or "2018-2-1" comes after "2018-11-1"

So if you can, try to convert your date you obtain to a sane format. The sanest format is computing the date-difference wrt an epoch. Unix has various tools that allow computing the number of seconds since the UNIX EPOCH of 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. This is what you are really after.

As you mention, your log-file has various date-formats, and this does not make things easy. Even though gnu awk has various [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions), they require that you know the format beforehand.

Since we do not know which formats exist in your log-file, we will make use of the unix function `date` which has a very elaborate interpreter that knows a lot of formats.

Also, I will make the assumption that in `awk` you are able to uniquely identify the date somehow store the date in a string called `date`. Maybe there is a special character always appearing after the date that allows you to do this:

Example input file:

```
2018-08-23 16:00 | some entry
Aug 23 2018 16:01:01 | some other entry
```

So, in this case, we can say:

```
awk -F| -v t1=$(date -d "START_DATE" "+%s") \
        -v t2=$(date -d "END_DATE" "+%s")   \
        '{date=$1}
         {cmd="date -d \""$1"\" +%s"; cmd | getline epoch; close cmd}
         (t1 <= epoch && epoch <= t2)' testfile
```